# One Command to Rule Both Colored Text and Invisible Text

Tags: text-manipulation

I have to send a paper to two different people.  For the first person, I have a bunch of questions that I would like to add throughout the paper and in color.  For the second person I don't want the questions to appear.  Is there any command I could define that I could use to do this?  For instance, define some kind of command \crazytext[parameter] so that when parameter=1 the text will be blue, but when parameter=0 it is not inserted into the paper.  This way I put a 1 in the preamble for the person I want to see blue text and a 0 in the preamble for the person for which I don't want text compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Define `\crazytext` in the following ways:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{\crazytext}[1][blue]{\textcolor{#1}}% parameter=1
%\newcommand{\crazytext}[1]{\ignorespaces}% parameter=0
```

In the first instance, `\crazytext` will insert `\textcolor{<color>}` as the replacement text for `\crazytext`. That is, `\crazytext{abc}` will result in `\textcolor{blue}{abc}`, while `\crazytext[red]{abc}` will result in `\textcolor{red}{abc}`.

In the second instance (commented above), `\crazytext` will gobble its argument and ignore any spaces following the command (to avoid spurious spaces).

Comment: Works just like I want.

Comment: Does the todo/todonotes package not satisfy this need ?